# Новый датафрейм из старого

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

У меня есть такая табличка

```
x = np.array([[3, 4, 3], [4, 3, 3], [3, 3, 4], [3, 3, 3], [2, 3, 4]])
x = x.T
y = np.array([2, 2, 1, 1, 2])
dataf = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=y)
print(dataf)
```

Я поделил массив заголовков вот так `[2, 1], [2, 1], [2]`. Как мне собрать соответствующие столбцы в массив массивов? То есть нужна новая табличка с колонками `[2, 1], [2, 1], [2]`. Столбцы каждой колонки состоят элементов, которые являются двумерным массивом. Поскольку двойке и единице соответствуют несколько столбцов, не важно как будут внутри будет состоять массив массивов.

Comment: Вы не могли бы привести пример желаемого результата?